# Add a headrule to the page style in a document class

Tags: header-footer, rules

I'm writing a thesis using the `thesis.cls` document class supplied by my own university. The university's own guidelines state that headers may be used in the thesis ''as long as there is a line across the entire page to separate the header from the text''. But using `\pagestyle{headings}` (a page style defined in the university's thesis class) does not make a horizontal rule.

Below is the relevant snippet that defines the `headings` page style.

```
\if@twoside 
 \def\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}                      % No feet.
    \def\@evenhead{\rmfamily \thepage\hfil \slshape \leftmark}            % Heading on left for even pages.        .
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape \rightmark}\hfil \rmfamily\thepage}           % Heading on right for odd pages. 
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
    \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}
   }
\else
   \def\ps@headings{
    \def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}                      % No feet.
    \def\@oddhead{{\slshape \rightmark} \hfil \rmfamily\thepage}          % Heading.
    \def\chaptermark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}
   }
\fi
```

How do I add a horizontal line under the headings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `\@evenhead` and `\@oddhead` *after* having set the your `\pagestyle{headings}`. That is, somewhere in your preamble, you should have the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\insertheaderrule}{\rlap{\rule[-.3\normalbaselineskip]{\textwidth}{.4pt}}}
\let\old@evenhead\@evenhead \let\old@oddhead\@oddhead
\def\@evenhead{\insertheaderrule\old@evenhead}% Prepend \insertheaderrule
\def\@oddhead{\insertheaderrule\old@oddhead}% Prepend \insertheaderrule
\makeatother
```

Above we create `\insertheaderrule` and prepend it to `\@evenhead` and `\@oddhead`. It sets a rule of length `\textwidth`, width `.4pt` and dropped 30% below the normal baseline skip. We ensure it doesn't take up space horizontally using `\rlap`.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no restriction apparently by the `thesis.cls` specifications that another package is forbidden, the easiest way is `fancyhdr`, for example, which provides the `fancy` pagestyle and has a rule below the header by default.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\blindtext[20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, the `fancy' page style from the `fancyhdr' package clashes with my universitys `thesis.cls'. The package loads just fine, but if I use `\pagestyle{fancy}' I get a bunch of errors: `Undefined control sequence \chapter', `Undefined control sequence \subsubsection', etc.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer: `A bunch of errors` is not useful -- you did not provide the link or even posted `thesis.cls`.

Comment: The class file (with identifying information about my university removed) is [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=36616872269697426366&t=3661687226969742636651971). Replacing `article` with `thesis` in your example above yields similar errors.